# Avoid nullary constructors used only for testing purposes - Allow mocked object method to throw exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, constructor, mocking

I want to test a method of a class. This class has 1 constructor with 3 parameters, which I can only supply one of the 3 requested.

I cannot mock the object because I am testing for invalid use, so **I need the test to expect an exception. Mocking the object results in no exception being thrown.**

**The problem with mocking**

```
public class NodeHandler {
    private List<Node> nodes;
    private Node currentNode;

    public NodeHandler(List<Node> nodes, Object obj1, Object obj2) {
        this.nodes = nodes;
        //uses obj1 and obj2; they cannot be null
    }

    public void initCurrentNode() {
        for(Node node : nodes) {
            if(node.canProcess()) {
                currentNode = node;
                return;
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalStateException("No nodes can be processed");
    }
}
```

The method I'm testing only depends on `List<Node> nodes`.

I manually initialize this myself (in the test) by accessing the field through reflection and setting the value:

```
public class MyTest {
    private NodeHandler mocked = Mockito.mock(NodeHandler.class);

    @Test(expected = IllegalStateException.class)
    public void testInvalidUsage() throws Exception {
        List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
        nodes.add(FirstNode.class.newInstance());
        nodes.add(SecondNode.class.newInstance());

        Field field = NodeHandler.class.getDeclaredField("nodes");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(mocked, nodes);

        try {
            method.invoke(manager);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new InvocationTargetException(e);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw (IllegalStateException) e.getTargetException();
        }
    }

    public static class FirstNode extends Node {
        public boolean canProcess() { return false; }
        public void process() { }
    }


    public static class SecondNode extends Node {
        public boolean canProcess() { return false; }
        public void process() { }
    }
}
```

This test fails, since it expects an `IllegalStateException`, but one is not thrown (due to the mock object).

**The nasty work-around**

I could declare a private nullary constructor in `NodeHandler`, set it to accessible. This will allow me to create an object whose methods may throw exceptions:

```
class NodeHandler {
    //...

    private NodeHandler() { }

    //...
}

public class MyTest {
    private NodeHandler manager;

    @Before
    public void init() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        Constructor<?> constructor = NodeHandler.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        manager = (NodeHandler) constructor.newInstance();
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalStateException.class)
    public void testInvalidUsage() throws Exception {
        //same as before
    }
}
```

This give me the results I want, but seems "hackish". I don't want to be required to declare a private constructor in every class I want to test.

**My Question**

Without being forced to declare a private nullary constructor, how could I test a method that's expected to throw an exception from an object without being required to fill all the parameters of the constructor for that object? Is there a way I can mock an object while still accounting for exceptions thrown by methods?

Comment: Maybe i misunderstood the handling of Obj 1 and Obj 2, but why not just set them `null`?

Comment: @ceekay The constructor makes use of `obj1` and `obj2`, so passing `null` would result in an NPE on creation.

Comment: Why don't you make your nodes variable package visible?

Comment: @fge Unless I'm misunderstanding you, which I probably am, I don't think that would make a difference to the current code (would still be forced to access the field through reflection, since `NodeHandler` is not located in the same package as the test). I would still need to instantiate `NodeHandler` to access the variable

Comment: Why don't you simply invoke the available public constructor, and pass two non-null obj1 and abj2, to make sure the constructor succeeds. You're testing a mocked Handler. That doesn't make much sense. Mock its collaborators instead.

Comment: @JBNizet It would result in an NPE, since the constructor uses these two objects. It would be easiest if I had the ability to create not necessarily a mock object, but an object with only what it needs for the method I want to test. This is possible by creating an "empty" object and setting the values myself, but it requires me to declare the nullary constructor, since the default constructor no longer exists

Comment: What I suggest is to pass **non-null** objects. Objects that will make your constructor run fine. If your constructor expects a String with at least 20 characters, then pass it a String with at least 20 characters. If it expects a Foo pass it a Foo, or a stubbed Foo.

Comment: @JBNizet I restructured my class to make it easier to test. I decided to pass `initCurrentNode` the collection, rather than have it depend on the field. Made it easier to test the method in isolation. Figured my difficulties testing came from bad design. I do have another question (about handling logic in the constructor; the reason for the NPE when instantiating `NodeManager`), but thats for another post. I realized mocking `NodeManager` was a bad idea (seeing how I'm testing it); I guess I just wanted to mock everything but what that method relied on, which would have been tedious